# Using dask for loop parallelization in nested loops

Tags: python, for-loop, dask

I am just learning to use dask and read many threads on this forum related to Dask and for loops. But I am still unclear how to apply those solutions to my problem. I am working with climate data that are functions of (time, depth, location). The 'location' coordinate is a linear index such that each value corresponds to a unique (longitude, latitude). I am showing below a basic skeleton of what I am trying to do, assuming var1 and var2 are two input variables. I want to parallelize over the location parameter 'nxy', as my calculations can proceed simultaneously at different locations.

```
for loc in range(0,nxy):           # nxy = total no. of locations
    for it in range(0,ntimes):    

       out1 = expression1 involving ( var1(loc), var2(it,loc) )
       out2 = expression2 involving ( var1(loc), var2(it,loc) )
       # <a dozen more output variables>
```

My questions:

(i) Many examples illustrating the use of 'delayed' show something like "delayed(function)(arg)". In my case, I don't have too many (if any) functions, but lots of expressions. If 'delayed' only operates at the level of functions, should I convert each expression into a function and add a 'delayed' in front?

(ii) Should I wrap the entire for loop shown above inside a function and then call that function using 'delayed'? I tried doing something like this but might not be doing it correctly as I did not get any speed-up compared to without using dask. Here's what I did:

```
def test_dask(n):
 for loc in range(0,n):
   # same code as before
 return var1  # just returning one variable for now

var1=delayed(tast_dask)(nxy)
var1.compute()
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every delayed task adds about 1ms of overhead.  So if your expression is slow (maybe you're calling out to some other expensive function), then yes dask.delayed might be a good fit.  If not, then you should probably look elsewhere.

In particular, it looks like you're just iterating through a couple arrays and operating element by element.  Please be warned that Python is very slow at this.  You might want to not use Dask at all, but instead try one of the following approaches:

1. Find some clever way to rewrite your computation with Numpy expressions
2. Use Numba

Also, given the terms your using like lat/lon/depth, it may be that Xarray is a good project for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I will look into Numba as well.